# Jquery on mouseenter and onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class <li> on hover and remove the class from <li> when clicked on a cancel button which is located in <li> submenu

```
<li class="live">
 <a href="#">Link</a>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li>Submenu Content</li>
    <div class="cancel-btn">Cancel</div>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Sounds great! Where are you stuck then?

Comment: Do you need to add a class? [CSS :hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)?

Comment: Please guide me on how the jQuery should be used

Comment: yes I have been using css hover but I want to hide the submenu on cancel button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed for the `li` with `live` class:

```
$('li.live').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('your_class') ;
}) ;

$('.cancel-btn').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.live').removeClass('your_class') ;
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually its better to give some ids to `li` and `div`. However you can do it with your classes.

```
$('.live').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('your class');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('your class');
});

$('.cancel-btn').click(function(){
  $('.live').removeClass('your class');
});
```

for hover see this: [jQuery Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

for click see this: [jQuery Click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 1):

You can compress it all into the `mouseenter` if you use `on` and `off` combined with [namespaced events (docs)](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names):

```js
$('.live').on('mouseenter',function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $that = $(this); // store $(this) so that it can be used in the next block...
    $('.cancel-btn').on('click.remove_class',function() { // bind namespaced click event handler
        $that.removeClass('active'); // ...use $(this) from parent block 
        $('.cancel-btn').off('click.remove_class'); // unbind namespaced event handler
    });
});
```

```css
.live.active {
    background: red;
    color: #FFF;
}

.submenu {
    display: none;
}

.live.active .submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="live">
 <a href="#">Link</a>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li>Submenu Content</li>
    <div class="cancel-btn">Cancel</div>
  </ul>
</li>
```